# Filter search in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, html, lwc-oss

HTML

```
<template>
    <lightning-card>
        <div class="slds-box slds-theme_default">
            <div class = " slds-grid slds-size_12-of-12">
                <lightning-combobox
                    class="slds-size_1-of-12"
                    name="referrer"
                    label="Referrer"
                    value={referrerValue}
                    placeholder="Select Referrer"
                    options={referrerOptions}
                    onchange={handleReferrerChange}
                ></lightning-combobox>

                <lightning-input 
                    class="slds-size_1-of-12 slds-var-p-left_small"
                    name="firstName" label="First Name" placeholder="Enter First Name"  value={firstNameValue} onchange={handlefirstNameValue}>
                </lightning-input>
                            
                <lightning-input 
                    class="slds-size_1-of-12 slds-var-p-left_small"
                    name="lastName" label="Last Name" placeholder="Enter Last Name"  value={lastNameValue} onchange={handlelastNameValue}>
                </lightning-input> 
                            
                <lightning-input 
                    class="slds-size_1-of-12 slds-var-p-left_small"
                    type="email" name="Email" label="Email" placeholder="Email" required  value={emailValue} onchange={handleEmailValue}>
                </lightning-input> 
                            
                <lightning-input 
                    class="slds-size_1-of-12 slds-var-p-left_small"
                    type="date" name="appointmentDate" label="Appointment Date" placeholder="Appointment Date"  value={dateValue} onchange={handledateValue}>
                </lightning-input> 

                <lightning-input 
                    class="slds-size_1-of-12 slds-var-p-left_small"
                    type="time" name="appointmentTime" label="Appointment Time" placeholder="Appointment Time"  value={timeValue} onchange={handletimeValue}>                    
                </lightning-input>

                <lightning-input 
                    class="slds-size_1-of-12 slds-var-p-left_small"
                    name="supplier" label="supplier" placeholder="Supplier" value={supplierValue} onchange={handlesupplierValue}>
                </lightning-input>

                <lightning-input 
                    class="slds-size_1-of-12 slds-var-p-left_small"
                    type="date" name="birthday" label="Birthday" placeholder="Birthday" value={birthdayValue} onchange={handlebirthdayValue}>
                </lightning-input>

                <lightning-button 
                    style="margin-top: 1.40rem;"
                    class="slds-size_2-of-12 slds-var-p-left_small"
                    variant="destructive" label="Show Appointment" title="Show Appointment" 
                    onclick={handleSearchKeyword}>
                </lightning-button>

                <lightning-button
                    style="margin-top: 1.40rem;"
                    variant="destructive"
                    label="Clear"
                    class="slds-size_2-of-12 slds-var-p-left_small"
                    onclick={handleClear}>
                </lightning-button>                
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-box slds-theme_default" >
            <div class = " slds-grid slds-size_12-of-12">
                <table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered slds-var-m-top_small"> 
                    <thead>
                       <tr class="slds-line-height_reset">
                          <th class="" scope="col">
                             <div class="slds-truncate" title="Member Name">Name</div>
                          </th>
                          <th class="" scope="col">
                             <div class="slds-truncate" title="Member's Email " >Member's Email</div>
                          </th>
                          <th class="" scope="col">
                             <div class="slds-truncate" title="Member's Status">Member's Status</div>
                          </th>
                          <th class="" scope="col">
                             <div class="slds-truncate" title="Order Number">Order Number</div>
                          </th>
                          <th class="" scope="col">
                             <div class="slds-truncate" title="Order Status">Order Status</div>
                         </th>
                         <th class="" scope="col">
                             <div class="slds-truncate" title="Appointment Date & Time ">Appointment Date & Time</div>
                         </th>
                         <th class="" scope="col">
                             <div class="slds-truncate" title="Appointment Status">Appointment Status</div>
                         </th>
                         <th class="" scope="col">
                             <div class="slds-truncate" title="Service name">Service name</div>
                         </th>
                         <th class="" scope="col">
                             <div class="slds-truncate" title="Max Allowance">Max Allowance</div>
                         </th>
                         <th class="" scope="col">
                             <div class="slds-truncate" title="Remaining Allowance">Remaining Allowance</div>
                         </th>
                         <th class="" scope="col">
                             <div class="slds-truncate" title="Re-Instate Allowance ">Re-Instate Allowance </div>
                         </th>
                       </tr>                
                   </thead>
                   <template if:true={Appointments__c}>
                        <template for:each={Appointments__c} for:item="Appointments__c">
                            <div class="slds-hint-parent" key={Appointments__c.Id}>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="slds-truncate">
                                    <p>Member Name - {Appointments__c.Order_Item__r.Orders__r.Account_Holder__r.Name}</p>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <p>Member's Email - {Appointments__c.Order_Item__r.Orders__r.Account_Holder__r.Email}</p>
                                <p>Member's Status - {Appointments__c.Order_Item__r.Orders__r.Account_Holder__r.Status__c}</p>
                                <p>Order Number - {Appointments__c.Order_Item__r.Orders__r.Name}</p>
                                <p>Order Status - {Appointments__c.Order_Item__r.Orders__r.Order_Status__c}</p>
                                <p>Appointment Date & Time - {Appointments__c.Appointment_Date_Time__c}</p>
                                <p>Appointment Status - {Appointments__c.Appointment_Status__c}</p>
                            </div>
                        </template>
                    </template>            
                </table>                                                        
            </div>
        </div>                   
    </lightning-card>    
</template>
```

use this html I get output like===>
[image]

[image]

but I want the output like ===>
[image]

In this image, I want when I put the email value and click on the show appointment button then get value like ==>[image]
how to achieve this output please give me a suggestion
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried [lightning-datatable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/example) ?. Try using Data table with row actions.

Comment: ya like that but it is a condition based on the show appointment button

Answer (score 0):

```html
<template if:true={Appointments__c} >
    <template for:each={Appointments__c} for:item="Appointments__c">
        <tr class="slds-hint-parent" key={Appointments__c.Id}>
            <td data-label="Member Name">
                <div class="slds-truncate"><a href="Appointments__c.Order_Item__r.Orders__r.Account_Holder__r.Name" target="_blank">{Appointments__c.Order_Item__r.Orders__r.Account_Holder__r.Name}</a></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </template>
</template>
```